# TypeScript Firebase Cloud Functions throw errors when I set types and when I don't set types

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

`firebase deploy --only functions` throws errors when I set Typescript types and when I don't set Typescript types. Here's my `index.ts`. The parameters for each function are set to `any`.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data: any, context: any) => {
    console.log("Hello world!")
    console.log(data);
    console.log(context);
});

exports.helloFirestore = functions.firestore.document('triggers/hello').onUpdate((change: any, context: any) => {
    console.log("Updated!");
    console.log(change.after.data());
    console.log(context.params.userId);
})
```

`firebase deploy --only functions` throws this error:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: 
Failed to generate manifest from function source: 
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
```

Removing the types stops that error:

```js
exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
```

But this throws another error:

```
Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

My guess is that there's an overzealous linter. I selected not to use ES Lint when I initialized Firebase Functions. I don't see a linter in `package.json`.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` could mean it managed to pass the compile stage but it's still seeing a .ts file because that sounds like a typical js error. `Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.` would be during compilation with tsconfig strict mode ([no implicit any](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny)). Can you check what your deploy package looks like / what kind of deploy setup do you have? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I played around with this some more. The way to get rid of the `Unexpected token ':'` error is to remove the data types from the parameters.

The way to get rid of the `Parameter 'data' implicitly has an 'any' type.` is to open `functions/tsconfig.json` and either change `strict` to `false` or to add this line:

```js
"noImplicitAny": false,
```

Both errors can be ignored and the functions will run.